# How to get the ID of the div the function was called from in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a jquery function ('rater') that I call this way:

```
<div id="someID"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#someID').rater({options});
</script>
```

I want to get the ID ('someID' in this case) so then I can use it inside the function as a variable.

Then I use it in something like this:

```
if (??? == 'someID') { do something }
```

How can I do it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrieving the selector used to call the plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    alert( this.selector );
};
```

You can access the selector as a property of the jQuery object.

So, if I called the plugin like this:

```
$('div #something').myPlugin();
```

Then "div #something" would be alerted.

---

Retrieving an element's ID from within a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    alert( this.attr('id') );
};
```

Comment: Matt, what on earth are you talking about? The answer you originally posted was 100% incorrect and was simply misleading - the answer I've posted DOES work... If you really think they are "functionally equivalent" then you need to learn jQuery's API properly.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you're trying to do this, but...

```
// create jQuery plugin method: "rater"
jQuery.fn.rater = function() 
{
  // `this` is a jQuery object: process each matched element
  return this.each(function()
  {
    // `this` is a single matched element. Process it, somehow...
    if ( this.id == "someID" )
    {
      // do something special
    }

    // normal rater logic, whatever that might be
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/selector)?

After reading your edited question again, it sounds as though you want the string of the id passed through.

```
<div id="someID"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#someID").rater({options},$("#someID").selector);
</script>
```

For efficiency sake, you can store the $("#someID") off in a variable if you like so you only do the query once.

Comment: There are examples on the page I linked to.

Comment: I mean, I need tho check if the 'selector' is == to something..

if (selector == 'some text') { do something }

Comment: selector should be able to get what you want. But I'm at a loss of where you want to put your check. Can you write a bit more code in your question to show what you want to do? It doesn't have to work--just give us a hint.

Comment: Why the heck is my answer voted down? He's asking for the string of the selector. That's exactly what jQuery's "selector" is for.

Comment: Is this some kind of practical joke?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I suspect he really just wants to find the ID of the element and is going along with the selector stuff because he doesn't know any better. +1 anyways.

Comment: @Paolo. OK. At least that makes sense. I shouldn't have answered what he asked. I should have answered what he should have asked. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will look for the closest "div" called, then get its attribute.

```
if ($(this).closest("div").attr("id") == "someId") {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $(this).attr('id') == 'someID' ) {
  // do stuff
}
```